# How do I make the system to recognize my dvd and cd drives

Tags: 11.10, drivers

I installed mythbuntu 11.10, but it doesn't recognize my DVD and CD drives on DELL desktop 8400. How do I make it to recognize them?
Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score 1):

You need the Medibuntu repository Ubuntu 11.10. Medibuntu (Multimedia, Entertainment & Distractions In Ubuntu) is a repository of packages that cannot be included into the Ubuntu distribution for legal reasons, copyright, license and patents (e.g.  advanced DVD playback support, multimedia codecs etc.)

To add Medibuntu repository, run the full command below at once:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

You can also run an additional command to add support for viewing Medibuntu packages in Ubuntu Software Center and bug reporting for crashes, if any.

```
sudo apt-get install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu
```